# Problem with Android's EditText : KeyListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener

On an `EditText` component, I'm trying to set a `KeyListener` in order to catch the ENTER key (for form validation).

```
    text.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                onKeyEnterPressedListener.onKeyEnterPressed(AKText.this);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getInputType() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content, int states) {

        }
    });
```

The problem is that whenever I type in the `EditText` using the keyboard, all the keys are ignored and it's ignoring my keystrokes. However, the softpad on the emulator's device is working.

How to fix this please?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would use the [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) class instead:

```
private TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

    }
    public void  beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
      // you can check for enter key here
    }
    public void  onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
    } 
};

EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_EDITTEXT_ID);
et.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

Comment: Great answer...the onKey listeners don't always work...this works! Thanks!

Comment: Is `TextWatcher` is call when EditText is Reload again

Comment: addTextChangedListener **  wasted a few mins finding it hehe.. caps C

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to use setOnKeyListener()?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnKeyListener(android.view.View.OnKeyListener)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i("KEY", Integer.toString(keyCode));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your returning false from your onKeyUp method, in android specifically the operations are handled after the onKeyUp method.

Also instead of using a KeyListener, most activities have an onKeyUp method you can override.

Here is a sample of some of my code I've been working on.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB) editText1.tab();
    if(event.isCtrlPressed())
    {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O) // ctrl+o
        {
            onClick(open);
        }
        else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_N) // ctrl+n
        {
            addFileTab(null);                   // add untitled tab
            editText1.setText("");
        }
        else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A) // ctrl+a
        {
            editText1.selectAll();
        }
        else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) // ctrl+s
        {
            onClick(save);
        }
        else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C) // ctrl+c
        {
            String selected = editText1.selection();
            ClipData clip;
            if(current != null) 
                clip = ClipData.newPlainText(current.getName() + " selection", selected);
            else
                clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Cerulean selection", selected);
            clipMan.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        }
        else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_P && clipMan.hasPrimaryClip()) // ctrl+p
        {
            if(clipMan.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))
            {
                CharSequence clip = clipMan.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).coerceToText(getBaseContext());
                editText1.insert(clip.toString());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    {
        onTabClicked(current, curTab);
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

I call the super classes onKeyUp for everything else. Hope it helps someone.

-c

UPDATE: This handle hardware keyboards only, for other operations use a TextWatcher.